# How to design a database for search history with multiple facets?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I want to show users a history of their searches, which can often be complicated:

- **any** of these terms: `[a,b,c]`
- **all** of these terms: `[d,e,f]`
- **not** these colors: `[h,i,j]`

Since these searches are done through a UI (not a search input where they would type "`a OR b etc...`") I assume I would need to store each value in a table.

Would it be overkill to create a table for each facet (`"search_terms", "search_colors", etc`)? or is there a simpler way?

```
| search_id |   term(_id)  | operator(enum)|
|:---------:|:------------:|:-------------:|
| 1         | blue         |     any       |
| 1         | green        |     any       |
| 1         | red          |     any       |
| 1         | musthave     |     all       |
| 1         | exclude_me   |     not       |
| 1         | exclude_also |     not       |
```

Some other considerations are:

- The web-URL can change over time, so I don't want to store that as an easy way out.
- The index/3rd party service I'm searching could change, so I similarly can't save the query I make.

(The terms themselves can be its own table with a reference instead).

Answer (score 0):

What you store should mimic what the user sees in the UI.  That way you can present it in a format that is familiar to him.

This format may, or may not, be anything close to the SQL that has ANDs and ORs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the way the UI sends the search to server and attempt to duplicate this data. Since you are using a 3rd party search engine I assume that you can configure it search text for specific terms and as a result you should be able to store the data search by search (all the info in one field). Probably with the exception of the user id (to restrict how's searches a user can search) and search id (primary key).